# How to use NotifyIcon in UWP \ C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I can't use the [NotifyIcon Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) in a project UWP
Some solution?

Answer (score 1):

NotifyIcon is only for Windows desktop applications.

In UWP you use Toast notifications if you want to show something to the user, as not all platforms that support UWP have a system tray (for example Xbox or Mobile)

Comment: But converted applications are supported.
They can be launched in the store.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think they are true UWP apps. They still use the Win32 API, but are packaged and running in a sandbox